# java.lang.NullPointerException** error?

Tags: java, sql-server, database, pointers, null

I am trying to add records to Sql Server in Java. In this function, program gives an error  like that:

```
Connected
1
2
Error java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It is the output..

Function is below:

```
public class DB {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt Nnull ;
    component cmp = new Component();

    public long pSave(Component cmp) {
        String i = cmp.getI();
        String s = cmp.getS();
        String a = cmp.getA();
        int t = cmp.getT();
        int c = cmp.getC();

        System.out.println("1");

        try {
            System.out.println("2");
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            System.out.println("3");
            String SQL =
                "INSERT INTO kisi (cl1,cl2,cl3,cl4,cl5) "
                + "VALUES(" + i + "," + s + "," + a + "," + c + "," + t + ")";

            System.out.println("4");
            stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);

            System.out.println("Success");

            return 1;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You didnt initialize the connection ('con') which you are calling when you're trying to initialize the statement.. ('stmt = con.createstatement')

Comment: Full stack trace please? Don't just print the Exception message, you're hiding what is really going on. At lest for this purpose, use e.printStackTrace()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Connection con = null;
......
stmt = con.createStatement();
        ^
```

The connection is not initialized. You have to connect to DB in order to retrieve data.

Answer (score 4):

NullPointerException means that you're trying to call a method on a null object.
That null object is your con that you never initialize.
You should add these two lines to initialize it:

```
Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://server:1433", "userName", "password");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Connection object first. You have:
    Connection con = null;

So, you cant create a statement from a connection that is null.

Answer (score 2):

You didnt initialize the connection `con` which you are calling when you're trying to initialize the statement.. `stmt = con.createstatement`

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of debugging may help.

You may notice your output says `Connected 1 2 Error java.lang.NullPointerException`.  The `1` and `2` suggest that you reached the first and second `println` statements and the `Error NPE` suggests that a line of code after those failed.  The third `println` is never hit, which means your NPE happened between 2 and 3.  There exists a single statement between these two, and that is where you are getting your NPE.

So the question now is, what could be causing the NPE?  I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.  :)